# Delete duplicate records and keep one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, duplicates

Using T-SQL.

My problem is I have a list of `usersid` and `locationid`.
A user can only have one location.

With the following query I get a list with all users with multiple location id's:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Userslocation
WHERE [USER] IN (
    SELECT [USER]  
    FROM Userslocation
    GROUP BY [User] 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
```

as result I get

```
location User
80653    83269
63150    83269
80653    84035
63150    84035
80653    85097
63150    85097
```

I want to get preserve one result and delete the rest

```
location User
80653    83269
80653    84035
80653    85097
```

Comment: How do you decide which records to keep...and which to delete?

Comment: Does it matter which location that's returned for a user?

Comment: the highest number is the new location number.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need something like a <kbd>CTE</kbd>

```
WITH UserslocationCTE AS (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [User] 
    ORDER BY location)'RowRank'
    FROM Userslocation)
DELETE FROM UserslocationCTE 
WHERE RowRank > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Return each user once, with the user's max location:

```
select user, max(location)
from tablename
group by user
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert an Incremental Id for the usersLocation. Then Delete the records which are greater than the first ID. for example.

```
Query
___
SELECT * 
FROM Userslocation
WHERE [USER] IN (
    SELECT [USER]  
    FROM Userslocation
    GROUP BY [User] 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
```

will show the below result

```
ID   location User
1    80653    83269
2    63150    83269
3    80653    84035
4    63150    84035
5    80653    85097
6    63150    85097
```

now you can do

```
 SELECT *
--or delete 
FROM Userlocation
WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT MIN(id)
        FROM Userlocation
        GROUP BY [USER]
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

        UNION

        SELECT MIN(id)
        FROM Userlocation
        GROUP BY [USER]
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        )
```